# nullPointerException with getSupportFragmentManager function

Tags: android, null

I need your help. I am trying to read the data from the sensors of the smart phone. That is why i tried to write some codes. After a while , i found a code on the Internet. But it does not work i do not know why. In this code , there are two pages for one to select a sensor and the other for the getting the data .

I am copying the codes here . And at the end i will tell you what the problem is.

Here is the MAIN activity code.

```
  package com.example.sensorlistactivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


  public class SensorListActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sensor_main);

    SensorSelectorFragment sensorSelect = (SensorSelectorFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_sensor_select);

    SensorDisplayFragment sensorDisplay = (SensorDisplayFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_sensor_view);

    sensorSelect.setSensorDisplay(sensorDisplay);
}

}
```

Here is the SENSOR SELECTOR CODE.

```
    package com.example.sensorlistactivity;

    import java.util.List;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SensorSelectorFragment extends ListFragment {

        private static final String TAG = "SensorSelectorFragment";
        private SensorDisplayFragment sensorDisplay;

        public void setSensorDisplay(SensorDisplayFragment sensorDisplay) {
            this.sensorDisplay = sensorDisplay;
            SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
            this.setListAdapter(new SensorListAdapter(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    sensors));
        }

        private void showSensorFragment(Sensor sensor) {
            sensorDisplay.displaySensor(sensor);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(this);
            ft.show(sensorDisplay);
            ft.addToBackStack("Showing sensor: " + sensor.getName());
            ft.commit();
        }

        private class SensorListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sensor> {

            public SensorListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                    List<Sensor> sensors) {

                super(context, textViewResourceId, sensors);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                final Sensor selectedSensor = getItem(position);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
                }
                ((TextView) convertView).setText(selectedSensor.getName());

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            Log.d(TAG,
                                    "display sensor! " + selectedSensor.getName());
                        }
                        showSensorFragment(selectedSensor);
                    }
                });
                return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the DISPLAYMENT CODE .

```
    package com.example.sensorlistactivity;

    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;

    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SensorDisplayFragment extends Fragment implements
            SensorEventListener {
        private static final String TAG = "SensorDisplayFragment";
        private static final String THETA = "\u0398";
        private static final String ACCELERATION_UNITS = "m/s\u00B2";
        private SensorManager sensorManager;
        private Sensor sensor;
        private TextView name;
        private TextView type;
        private TextView maxRange;
        private TextView minDelay;
        private TextView power;
        private TextView resolution;
        private TextView vendor;
        private TextView version;
        private TextView accuracy;
        private TextView timestampLabel;
        private TextView timestamp;
        private TextView timestampUnits;
        private TextView dataLabel;
        private TextView dataUnits;
        private TextView xAxis;
        private TextView xAxisLabel;
        private TextView yAxis;
        private TextView yAxisLabel;
        private TextView zAxis;
        private TextView zAxisLabel;
        private TextView singleValue;
        private TextView cosLabel;
        private TextView cos;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_view, null);
            sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            name = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.name);
            type = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.type);
            maxRange = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.maxRange);
            minDelay = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.minDelay);
            power = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.power);
            resolution = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.resolution);
            vendor = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.vendor);
            version = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.version);
            accuracy = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.accuracy);
            timestampLabel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.timestampLabel);
            timestamp = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            timestampUnits = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.timestampUnits);
            dataLabel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dataLabel);
            dataUnits = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dataUnits);
            xAxis = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.xAxis);
            xAxisLabel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.xAxisLabel);
            yAxis = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.yAxis);
            yAxisLabel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.yAxisLabel);
            zAxis = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.zAxis);
            zAxisLabel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.zAxisLabel);
            singleValue = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.singleValue);
            cosLabel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cosLabel);
            cos = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cos);

            layout.findViewById(R.id.delayFastest).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sensorManager
                                    .unregisterListener(SensorDisplayFragment.this);
                            sensorManager.registerListener(
                                    SensorDisplayFragment.this, sensor,
                                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
                        }
                    });

            layout.findViewById(R.id.delayGame).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sensorManager
                                    .unregisterListener(SensorDisplayFragment.this);
                            sensorManager.registerListener(
                                    SensorDisplayFragment.this, sensor,
                                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
                        }
                    });

            layout.findViewById(R.id.delayNormal).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sensorManager
                                    .unregisterListener(SensorDisplayFragment.this);
                            sensorManager.registerListener(
                                    SensorDisplayFragment.this, sensor,
                                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                        }
                    });

            layout.findViewById(R.id.delayUi).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            sensorManager
                                    .unregisterListener(SensorDisplayFragment.this);
                            sensorManager.registerListener(
                                    SensorDisplayFragment.this, sensor,
                                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
                        }
                    });
            return layout;
        }

        public void displaySensor(Sensor sensor) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "display the sensor");
            }
            this.sensor = sensor;
            name.setText(sensor.getName());
            type.setText(String.valueOf(sensor.getType()));
            maxRange.setText(String.valueOf(sensor.getMaximumRange()));
            // minDelay.setText(String.valueOf(sensor.getMinDelay()));
            power.setText(String.valueOf(sensor.getPower()));
            resolution.setText(String.valueOf(sensor.getResolution()));
            vendor.setText(String.valueOf(sensor.getVendor()));
            version.setText(String.valueOf(sensor.getVersion()));
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            switch (accuracy) {

            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH:
                this.accuracy.setText("SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH");
                break;
            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM:
                this.accuracy.setText("SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM");
                break;
            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW:
                this.accuracy.setText("SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW");
                break;
            case SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE:
                this.accuracy.setText("SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE");
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            onAccuracyChanged(event.sensor, event.accuracy);
            timestampLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timestamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timestamp.setText(String.valueOf(event.timestamp));
            timestampUnits.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            switch (event.sensor.getType()) {

            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                showEventData("Acceleration - gravity on axis", ACCELERATION_UNITS,
                        event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                showEventData("Abient Magnetic Field", "uT", event.values[0],
                        event.values[1], event.values[2]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
                showEventData("Angular speed around axis", "radians/sec",
                        event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT:
                showEventData("Ambient light", "lux", event.values[0]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE:
                showEventData("Atmospheric pressure", "hPa", event.values[0]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY:
                showEventData("Distance", "cm", event.values[0]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY:
                showEventData("Gravity", ACCELERATION_UNITS, event.values[0],
                        event.values[1], event.values[2]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION:
                showEventData("Acceleration (not including gravity)",
                        ACCELERATION_UNITS, event.values[0], event.values[1],
                        event.values[2]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:
                showEventData("Rotation Vector", null, event.values[0],
                        event.values[1], event.values[2]);
                xAxisLabel.setText("x*sin(" + THETA + "/2)");
                yAxisLabel.setText("y*sin(" + THETA + "/2)");
                zAxisLabel.setText("z*sin(" + THETA + "/2)");
                if (event.values.length == 4) {
                    cosLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cos.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[3]));
                }
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION:
                showEventData("Angle", "Degrees", event.values[0], event.values[1],
                        event.values[2]);
                xAxisLabel.setText(R.string.azimuthLabel);
                yAxisLabel.setText(R.string.pitchLabel);
                zAxisLabel.setText(R.string.rollLabel);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY:
                showEventData("Relatice ambient air humidity", "%", event.values[0]);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE:
                showEventData("Ambien temperature", "degree Celcius",
                        event.values[0]);
                break;
            }
        }

        private void showEventData(String label, String units, float x, float y,
                float z) {
            dataLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dataLabel.setText(label);
            if (units == null) {
                dataUnits.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                dataUnits.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                dataUnits.setText("(" + units + "):");
            }
            singleValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            xAxisLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            xAxisLabel.setText(R.string.xAxisLabel);
            xAxis.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            xAxis.setText(String.valueOf(x));
            yAxisLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            yAxisLabel.setText(R.string.yAxisLabel);
            yAxis.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            yAxis.setText(String.valueOf(y));
            zAxisLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            zAxisLabel.setText(R.string.zAxisLabel);
            zAxis.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            zAxis.setText(String.valueOf(z));
        }

        private void showEventData(String label, String units, float value) {

            dataLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dataLabel.setText(label);
            dataUnits.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dataUnits.setText("(" + units + "):");
            singleValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            singleValue.setText(String.valueOf(value));
            xAxisLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            xAxis.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            yAxisLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            yAxis.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            zAxisLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            zAxis.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
            super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
            if (hidden) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unregistering listener");
                }
                sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
                Log.d(TAG, "Unregistering listener");
            }
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

        }
    }
```

Here is the problem : when I run this code , there is nullPointerExpection .
In the main activity , "sensorSelect" and "sensorDisplay" are null. In other words , this part does not work.

```
    SensorSelectorFragment sensorSelect = (SensorSelectorFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_sensor_select);

    SensorDisplayFragment sensorDisplay = (SensorDisplayFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_sensor_view);
```

Why is that so ? 
Also i am using two layout .xml file . one of them sensor_main which is called by main code and the other one is sensor_view .

I am putting these codes also here , there could be a problem also with these since i do not understand how could it be possible two layout xml files.

SENSOR_MAIN.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_sensor_select"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="root.gast.playground.sensor.SensorSelectorFragment" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_sensor_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="root.gast.playground.sensor.SensorDisplayFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

SENSOR_VIEW.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/sensorRateSelector" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/delayFastest"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST"
                    android:checked="false"/>

                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/delayGame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SENSOR_DELAY_GAME"
                    android:checked="false"/>

                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/delayNormal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL"
                    android:checked="true"/>

                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/delayUi"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SENSOR_DELAY_UI"
                    android:checked="false"/>
            </RadioGroup>

            <View android:id="@+id/seperator"
                style="@style/line_separator"
                android:layout_below="@id/sensorRateSelector" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/seperator"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Name:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nameLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/nameLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/nameLabel" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/typeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/nameLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/nameLabel"
                android:text="Type:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/typeLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/typeLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/typeLabel"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/maxRangeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/nameLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/typeLabel"
                android:text="Max Range:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/maxRange"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maxRangeLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/maxRangeLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/maxRangeLabel"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/minDelayLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/maxRangeLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/maxRangeLabel"
                android:text="Min Delay:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/minDelay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/minDelayLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/minDelayLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/minDelayLabel"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/powerLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/minDelayLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/minDelayLabel"
                android:text="Power:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/power"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/powerLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/powerLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/powerLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/power"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/power"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/power"
                android:text="mA"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/resolutionLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/powerLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/powerLabel"
                android:text="Resolution:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/resolution"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/resolutionLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/resolutionLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/resolutionLabel"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/vendorLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/resolutionLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/resolutionLabel"
                android:text="Vendor:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/vendor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vendorLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/vendorLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/vendorLabel"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/versionLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/versionLabel"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/vendorLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/vendorLabel"
                android:text="Version:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/version"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/versionLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/versionLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/versionLabel"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/accuracyLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/versionLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/versionLabel"
                android:text="Accuracy:"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/accuracy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/accuracyLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/accuracyLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/accuracyLabel"/>

            <!-- timestamp -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/timestampLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/accuracyLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/accuracyLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:text="Timestamp:" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timestampLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/timestampLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/timestampLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/timestampUnits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timestamp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/timestamp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/timestamp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="(ns)" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/dataLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/accuracyLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/timestampLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/dataUnits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dataLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/dataLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/dataLabel"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/singleValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dataUnits"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/dataUnits"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/dataUnits"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <!-- X axis -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/xAxisLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/dataLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/dataLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="@string/xAxisLabel" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/xAxis"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/xAxisLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/xAxisLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/xAxisLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <!-- Y axis -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/yAxisLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/xAxisLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/xAxisLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="@string/yAxisLabel" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/yAxis"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/yAxisLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/yAxisLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/yAxisLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <!-- Z axis -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/zAxisLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/yAxisLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/yAxisLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="@string/zAxisLabel" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/zAxis"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/zAxisLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/zAxisLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/zAxisLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <!-- cos value (for rotation vector only) -->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/cosLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/zAxisLabel"
                android:layout_below="@id/zAxisLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="cos(\u0398/2):" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/cos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cosLabel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/cosLabel"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cosLabel"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your manifest, I cannot answer this 100%, but I think what is going on is the app cannot build the display because it cannot reference your Sensor Fragments. Here is your package declaration for SensorDisplayFragment:

```
package com.example.sensorlistactivity;
```

so to use then in an xml file, you should have this as your class:

```
class="com.example.sensorlistactivity.SensorDisplayFragment" />
```